# Swapping the largest item in an array with the first position item

Tags: java

I need to find the largest number in array bb and swap it with the first item. I was able to find the largest number and move it to the front, but I can't get the item in the first position to swap. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrayTest
{

public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    int bb[] = { -9, 55, 10002, -222, 45, -1, 926, 100, -100 };
    int i, temp;
    int bbLen = bb.length;
    
    System.out.println ("Before: " + Arrays.toString(bb));
   
    int large = bb[0];
    for (i = 0; i < bbLen; i++)
    {
      if (large < bb[i])
         large = bb[i];
   
      
    }
    temp = large;
    large = bb[0];
    bb[0] = temp;
  
    System.out.println ("After:  " + Arrays.toString(bb));



    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to keep the position and the value of the largest number.

When you have it :

```java
bb[index_bigger] = bb[0];
bb[0] = larger;
```

Hope help you

Comment: Where would this go?  would I add the bb[I] = bb[0] before the for loop or after? I am still a little lost, but thank you for the help!

Comment: In your loop, each time you see a bigger value than the actuel, you keep his value. You should keep his index too. It's when you go out of for loop that you need to swap the value.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I keep getting [10002, -9, 55, 10002, 10002, 10002, 10002, 10002, 10002]

Comment: I think you put my code in your loop. You're not supposed too. It's when you have recover the largest number of your array that you can swap the value

Comment: `int large = bb[0];
   for (i = 0; i < bbLen; i++)
   {
      if (large < bb[i])
        large = bb[i];
        bb[i] = bb[0];
        
      
   }
   
   temp = large;
   large = bb[0];
   bb[0] = temp;
 ` Not sure what is wrong

Comment: You don't recover the index like i said.
```
        int large = bb[0];
        for (i = 0; i < bbLen; i++)
        {
          if (large < bb[i]) {
              large = bb[i];
              index = i;
          }
        }
        
        bb[index] = bb[0];
        bb[0] = large;
```